# jQuery Mobile not working with PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) application and am using [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile). The last time I was working on the project it was looking great, but now jQuery Mobile stopped working. What's going on?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Login To Carpool Mobile</h2>
            <p align="right"><a href="registration.html" id="showregistration">Don't have an account? &rarr;</a></p>
                <form method="post" id="loginForm">

                    <label for="password">Email:</label>
                    <input class="required" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username@target.com">

                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="required" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">

                    <input type="button" value="Login" id="submitButton" onClick="handleLogin()">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            checkPreAuth();
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nope, it's just displaying in regular HTML format

Comment: If it is not a problem, mail me your project and I will fix it for you. Nothing here should cause jQM to load without its style.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I have the same issue, even simple page is not working when I am adding jquery mobile js but without adding js file it is working fine in emulator.

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap requires you to manually set/allow aspects of your app in your "config.xml" file in the root directory.

The solution you are looking for, I believe, is this line:

```
<access origin="http://code.jquery.com" subdomains="true" />
```

You are allowing access to the external resource of "http://code.jquery.com" and allowing all of its subdomains.  This means that you have just unlocked jquery mobile, which is what you are going for, as seen by your script tags:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> These "src" attributes are now seen as "subdomains" of http://code.jquery.com, which you have just successfully allowed!

Comment: Hi, do you have a gist that shows exactly where that line goes?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use below one with jQuery Mobile

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkPreAuth();
});
```

You need to use custom jQuery Mobile specific events. You may have to change your code as below.

```
$('#page').live('pageshow', function(event){
    checkPreAuth();             
});
```

Check documentation for [more relevant events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).

From your code I can notice that you are using very old libraries of both jQuery and jQuery Mobile. I would recommend you to upgrade to the latest [library](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) which will enable you to use much more features than what you have in your current version.

Here is an example with [latest framework](http://jsfiddle.net/AKn6S/1/) from jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problem with your code apart that `checkPreAuth();` is not defined. You should also try to update your version of query and jquery mobile.
I will recommend that you download and include should include the JQuery mobile and Jquery files( script files) in your **www** project directory

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `$(document).ready(function()` and keep `checkPreAuth();` inside the deviceready event of PhoneGap.

Comment: That is a wrong approach. You should not call the function before loading the dom.

Comment: I do that in my project and it works great.The file is loaded from local dir so when it hits the script tag, the DOM is loaded.

Comment: This is correct for normal jQuery projects but not for jQuery Mobile projects. Check out awesome explanation by Gajotres here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events/14469041#14469041

Comment: In PhoneGap DOM is always loaded from local file. So this check is not required if u write our init code in the scripts tag. we do that all the time.

Comment: I think you don't get the point. the way jQuery-Mobile loads the files into DOM is different (It uses ajax). It may seem correct but you'll end up with peculiar bugs.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan - I do get the point. All UI frameworks works the same way. My expertise is more with Kendo UI Mobile.